# PHP Array & Pointer Confusion

Tags: php, arrays, pointers

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
function z($zzz){
   for($c=0;$c<5;$c++){
   $zzz[$c]= 10;  
   //more and more codes
   }    
}
```

I want to write a `loop` so that

the 1st time the function is executed,  **argument `$array` is passed**

the 2nd time : **argument  `$array[0]` is passed**

while the 3rd time : **argument  `$array[1]` is passed**

.....

and the 12th time :   **argument  `$array[0][0]` is passed**

This is what comes to my mind:

```
$a = -1;
$b = -1;
$array = array();

while($a<10){
    while($b<10){
         z($array);
         $b++;
         $array= &$array[$b];
    }
    $a++;
    $array= &$array[$a];  
}
```

I've tried it but it didn't work..

I would appreciate if someone can provide a solution..

Comment: It will be difficult to provide a solution because we have no idea what you are doing. Try to explain it better.

Comment: And know that indenting code within control structures (while loops etc) makes it soooo much easier to read

Comment: yes, please explain it better

Comment: Your function `z()` is modifying the array but it's not returning anything. Follow @Jack's answer and make it so that the function takes the reference to the array, not its copy and then try again.

Comment: I've rephrased my words I hope it is more comprehensible now.

Comment: @N.B. oh... yeah.. You are right! I should pass the argument as a pointer to the array instead of an array..

Comment: and change ` for($c=0;$c>5;$c++)` to ` for($c=0;$c<5;$c++)`

Comment: @ArchJ No, you should not do call-time pass by reference, instead the function should have the reference symbol before the parameter; as mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Jack yeah that's what I was trying saying.. Sorry didn't express it properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If z() is supposed to change the passed array, your function definition should be:

```
function z(&$zzz)
```

Comment: and change ` for($c=0;$c>5;$c++)` to ` for($c=0;$c<5;$c++)`

Comment: @dInGd0nG sorry about `for($c=0;$c>5;$c++)` it was a typo.. And the codes work now! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 0;
while ($a < 99)         // <-- edit as applicable
{
   $b = 0
   while ($b < 12)
   {
      if ($b == 0)
      {
         Z($array[$a]);
      } else
      {
         Z($array[$a][$b]);
      }
     $b++;
   }
   $a++;
}
```

And as stated by Jack you need to pass the `$array` variable by reference for update. Not too sure what that function is trying to achieve though. If you need to fill an array with a predermined dimension, maybe `array_fill` could be more useful.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

```
function z(&$zzz){
   for($c=0;$c<5;$c++){
      $zzz[$c]= 10;  
      //more and more codes
   }    
}
```